# How to end an infinite loop by running another function

Tags: python, html, function, loops, while-loop

Is there a way that I can make an infinite loop end when another function is run?

I have this loop:

```
def SPARKLES():
    while True:
        pixel = random.choice(tree)
        pixel.color = random_color()
```

and I want that loop to stop when I run this function:

```
def OFF():
    tree.off()
```

The functions are triggered by a html button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
needToExit = False

def SPARKLES():
    while not needToExit:
        pixel = random.choice(tree)
        pixel.color = random_color()

def OFF():
    needToExit = True
```

Remember that you will need multithreading to handle this kind of action (the process where you call `SPARKLES` will be blocked).

Comment: I beg you, never use == False use not needToExit

Comment: Correct @IceflowerS, updated. Thanks!